# SQL Server linked server data flow

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 3 distinct servers: Data, Settings and Source.

From the settings server I call an insert that takes data from the source server and inserts it into the data server using the following statement:

From settings instance:

```
exec lnk_Data.db_on_data.dbo.sp_executesql 
   'insert into tbl_on_data
   select * from Source.db_on_source.dbo.tbl_on_source'
```

Is this similar to an insert statment that I run directly from the data machine?

From data machine:

```
insert into tbl_on_data
select * from Source.db_on_source.dbo.tbl_on_source
```

I would like to know if the flow of data from the source to the data is similar in the two cases.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, flow of data is exactly same in all perspective.